# set density parameter for imagick with php

Tags: php, pdf, png, imagick

I want to convert a pdf page to a png image with Imagick.

I tried with PHP, but the image quality was very low.
When I tried with command line, the result was perfect.

**PHP code**

```
$im = new imagick( __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$PDFName.'['.$i.']' );  
$params = $im->identifyImage();
$width = $params['geometry']['width']*1;
$height = $params['geometry']['height']*1;
$im->setResolution(400,400);
$im->resizeImage($width ,$height, imagick::FILTER_SINC, 1, true);
$im->writeImage(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'pdf_pages\\'.$i.'.png'); 
$im->clear(); 
$im->destroy();
```

**Command line code**

```
convert -density 400 a.pdf -resize 25% -a.png
```

**PHP code (2nd attempt)**

```
$im = new imagick( __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$PDFName.'['.$i.']' );  
$im->setOption('density','400x400');
$im->setOption('resize','25%');
$im->writeImage(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'pdf_pages\\'.$i.'.png'); 
$im->clear(); 
$im->destroy();
```

Still bad results.

What can I do? I want to use the density parameter in my PHP code, but how?

**Output with PHP**
[image]

**Output with command line**
[image]

Comment: You should provide the PDF file as well.

Comment: Here is PDF file => http://www.cevhersys.net/5663.pdf

Comment: Also, if the PHP API fails to get you what you need, you can always resort back to using `exec` or `shell_exec` to execute the command and generate the file you need.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to set Resolution **before** you read the file.

```
$im = new imagick();
$im->setResolution(200,200);
$im->readImage(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$PDFName.'['.$i.']');
```

Than, the result will be perfect.
Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 5):

From the manual http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setresolution.php

> Imagick::setResolution() must be called before loading or creating an image.

See this answer [Pdf to image using php-imagick api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211913/pdf-to-image-using-php-imagick-api/4211949#4211949)