# how to get a better resolution with imagemagick and php?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have stored a PDF, and I want to convert it to JPG and increasing the size of the photo with imagemagick. It works ok, but It return me a photo with bad resolution
http://goo.gl/Gj7bE

```
$save_toB = $uploaddir . "/" . $pdfNameB;
$imga2 = new imagick($pdfB . '[0]');
$imga2->scaleImage(2500, 2400);
$imga2->setImageFormat('jpg');
$imga2->writeImages($save_toB, true);
```

Comment: Is the original image size smaller than 2500x2400?

Answer (score 3):

Add setResolution before loading the Image:

Something like:

```
$save_toB = $uploaddir . "/" . $pdfNameB;
$imga2 = new imagick();
$imga2->setResolution(300,300);
$imga2->readImage($pdfB . '[0]')
```

Also read this: [Pdf to image using php-imagick api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211913/pdf-to-image-using-php-imagick-api)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Upscaling an image will always result in blurry images.

Even Photoshop, which is supposed to be the most powerful image manipulation software produces blurred photos when you enlarge a small photo.

These software are not able to extrapolate the extra pixels needes to enlarge a small photo.

The best option would be to pick up a higher res image to start with.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php

> Note: The behavior of the parameter bestfit changed in Imagick 3.0.0.
>   Before this version given dimensions 400x400 an image of dimensions
>   200x150 would be left untouched. In Imagick 3.0.0 and later the image
>   would be scaled up to size 400x300 as this is the "best fit" for the
>   given dimensions. If bestfit parameter is used both width and height
>   must be given.

maybe it was helpful